# \def error in Latex

Tags: python, latex

I'm trying to use the \def\variableName{variable} function found from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) to pass variables from subprocess in Python to my Latex script. If I use certain words as the variable name the script doesn't run and I get this 'error' (I say 'error' as it isn't really an error but the program just stops here).

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)
    entering extended mode
    LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
    Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
*`

For some reasons this works:

`subprocess.call('pdflatex "\def\city{'+sys.argv[1][(sys.argv[1].rfind(os.sep))+1:-4]+'} \
    \def\collisions{'+str(accidentDistributionList[0])+'} \
    \def\collisionsb{'+str(accidentDistributionList[1])+'} \
    \input{Summary.tex}"', shell=True)`

But this doesn't:

`subprocess.call('pdflatex "\def\city{'+sys.argv[1][(sys.argv[1].rfind(os.sep))+1:-4]+'} \
    \def\collisions{'+str(accidentDistributionList[0])+'} \
    \def\nearmisses{'+str(accidentDistributionList[1])+'} \
    \input{Summary.tex}"', shell=True)`

Wondering if anyone has come across this problem or Latex will only accept certain words as variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone stumbles upon this I've found the solution.

When defining `def\nearmiss{variable}` Python was reading the escape character `\n` so all I had to do was `def\\nearmiss{variable}` and it worked.

Hope that helps someone!